# Converting an arbitraty string to a math expression

Tags: c#, math, expression

Is it possible to convert any string (eg. "x^2-3x+4" or "x^3/(exp(x)-1)") to a math expression so that i can use this in a method like:

```
public static void Function(double x, ref double y)
    {
        y = ConvertStringToMathExpression("x^3/(exp(x)-1)");
    }
```

I know that there are other posts on "Converting a string to a math expression", but all of them are asking for an algorithm for an already know string. I'd like to input the math expression during runtime.

Is symbolic differentiation very difficult to do? I am still a beginner with c# and don't know if I can do this. Is there a decent documentation on how to do symbolic differentiation?

Comment: Maybe ["NCalc"](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/) can help...

Comment: I think you took this task too early if you don't know basics in C#. I can't understand your example at all. Though, there is plenty of frameworks which do the same thing of parsing this queries and convert them to expression tree. If you want to do it yourself, well, start with Grammar parsers, and then you can try to create your own grammar in ANTLR framework.

Comment: @L.B Thanks that worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, maybe it can help other people figuring out how to use NCalc:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NCalc;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public ExpressionString expressi = new ExpressionString("pow([x],3)/(exp(x)-1)");
    public void FunctionInt(double x, double xminusa, double bminusx, ref double y, object obj)
    {
        Expression e = new Expression(expressi.expression, EvaluateOptions.IgnoreCase);
        e.Parameters["x"] = x;
        object result = e.Evaluate();
        y = Convert.ToDouble(result);
    }
}
```